# ksh ide for windows?

Tags: windows, linux, ksh

i am looking for a linux shell environment for windows 7. is there `.ksh` or any shell environment that runs on windows? cygwin is somehow different and i cannot run for example `vi test.txt` in cygwin, i dont know why.

what i want is that i should be able to write code in kornshell and to run it by double-clicking the .ksh file.

there is a linux shell enrivonment for windows called ADP shell which i use at job, but i cannot find it online..

can someone help me find this, i need this for my new job.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) it could be usefull for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ksh for Windows is part of [UWIN](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/uwin/uwin.html)

However, it does not contain an IDE.  Would be nice though.

Answer (score 0):

The default Cygwin installation does not install vi. Vi is available as vim in the Editors category of the Cygwin setup application.